# Highcharts as spring boot service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

A noob here.
I am exploring the capabilities of AngularJS, Spring Boot and Highcharts.
I want to know if we can build following funtionality:

1. If I call pieExpenses.html it should just render a page with pie chart.
2. If call index.html, I should be able render other content along with pieChart (pieExpenses.html) inside it.

I was able to find example for functionality 1 using [this project](https://dreamix.eu/blog/java/real-time-reporting-with-highcharts-angularjs-and-spring-boot), but was confused with functionality 2.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood it correctly, so you are basically looking for a way to set up routing and render the same component on two different pages?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant

Comment: Unfortunately, I am familiar with the Angular 2+ only, but I am pretty sure that the following tutorial should help you: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09